# How can I find files within a directory containing paths to /bin but not shbangs?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell

I want find all files inside of a directory that make a call to /bin executable, but I do not want to include shbangs, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/bin/bash
```

All other files containing the path should be listed and show the code making the call.

Comment: You want to list all files inside a certain numbers of directory and want to exclude those that begins with `#!/usr/bin/perl` or `#!/bin/bash`, right?

Comment: what do you mean by 'show what the system call its used'? My definition of system calls are C-language functions that access functionality in the OS. `stat` would be an appropriate example for information about files, but it won't change from one file to another. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or with only 2 greps:

```
grep -r /bin * | grep -Pv '.*?:#!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$ grep -H -r '.*' *|grep -v '^#!'|grep /bin/
```